# Replacing data with another data using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

Can i replace a big text like `During the day, abc is working.` with new text `abc is happy to work.` using only regular expressions. This was asked in some text papers. And it also said that code cannot be more then 2 lines.

/*** update ***/
I have written code like

```
<?php


echo preg_replace(array('/During the day,/','/is/'), array('','is happy to'), 'During the day, Damien is working');
?>
```

and it worked. Just wanted to know if it can be better.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @JackManey - I have written code like <?php


echo preg_replace(array('/During the day,/','/is/'), array('','is happy to'), 'During the day, Damien is working');
?> and it worked. Just wanted to know if it can be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for is preg_replace() http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php. If you need to test your regex, I recommend http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: i know the function. This should be done in jsut 2 lines. So asked if it can be done

Comment: if you use the right regex absolutely